# What's this round blue gear piece from set 76911?

Tags: part-identification, gears

[image: piece to identify]

This piece was in with all of set 76911's spare pieces in a separate bag. 76911 is the only Speed Champions set I have so I don't know if the piece comes in any others. I looked at the inventory for 76911 on Brickset & BrickLink and the piece isn't listed there (I also looked through New Elementary's blog posts on new pieces and I couldn't find them mentioning it either).

It seems like a utility part like the brick seperator or wrench/crowbar, but its two holes at each end are too small to do anything: the large one is too small to connect to a stud and the small one is too small to fit a rod into. So this piece is completely bizarre to me...

Comment: Does the piece have a LEGO marking? If not (my suspicion), then it is likely that it is not an official part, but a piece of machinery or equipment that somehow fell into the bags at the packaging facility. You should probably contact LEGO with it, they would surely be interested to look into what it is, where did it come from and which of their machines is missing a piece.

Comment: Typically, spare parts don't come in a separate bag. Can you clarify whether this bag came with an unopened official lego set ? Or might this part have found its way in the bag after it was opened ?

Comment: @zovits Oh that's really interesting, I was starting to suspect something like that might have happened because this piece really doesn't seem to connect with Lego... I'll look into contacing Lego tomorrow then!

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I was surprised all the spare parts were together, I've never seen that before but I assumed that maybe it's just a new thing with Speed Racers sets (or sets in general). Yes, this piece 100% came with the set. My dad built the car, but he didn't need anything in this small bag of spare parts so he left it unopened (I don't know which bag, 1 or 2, this bag was with). I then opened it and this blue piece was in there with all the spare parts and the wrench piece.

Comment: Interesting. If you get an explanation from Lego, please let us know (you can [self-answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) your question with it). I'm intrigued.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a blue [Non-Vented Double Dead-Ender Cap](https://www.qosina.com/non-vented-double-dead-ender-cap-blue-12092) (or a variation thereof), also called a [Luer taper/lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luer_taper), sold by various OEM suppliers. According to the supplier [KempCo Specialties](https://www.kempcospec.com/Universal-Male-Female-Luer-Cap-Blue-PP-p/kitcp-pp-blu.htm), these are multi-purpose fittings that are used in various industries including industries that involve pneumatics.

I suspect either the injecting molding machines or the dye mixers use these caps. You should report this to LEGO, alongside whatever batch markings are on the box, so they can track down when and where it happened. As for the piece, I guess you now own a part of the LEGO production process :)

I figured this out by employing Google Lens and having Google compare the photo with images online.

[image: Non-Vented Double Dead-Ender Cap]

Comment: So, it seems there's a Lego factory somewhere which has a missing nozzle?

Comment: Nice find ! Some speculation : [this supplier](https://www.kempcospec.com/Universal-Male-Female-Luer-Cap-Blue-PP-p/kitcp-pp-blu.htm) mentions it can also be used for several non-medical applications - one of which is pneumatics. A Lego factory probably has many uses for pneumatics during manufacture and/or packaging of lego parts. Looking forward to Lego's response.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker thanks! I've expanded my answer some more and included additional links. After watching several videos on the brick production process I did notice several other luer locks in use, especially on the dye mixers, so chances are it originated there.

Comment: Fascinating answer! Marking as accepted since you actually found out what it is, which I wasn't expecting! As you can see in my answer I just posted, it doesn't actually have a Lego factory origin... But the pneumatic/medical stuff is interesting: my dad was in the hospital for a leg infection when he made the set, and he had some kind of tube device stuck into his wound to keep the blood circulating, so maybe the piece came off of that..? Or maybe his bed. So it's not a Lego factory that's missing this piece, it's a hospital!

Answer (score 13):

Ok everyone, I have a disappointing update but it does answer my question. I didn't actually get round to contacting Lego about this because I mentioned my discoververy to my mum first. She immediately said "Oh your father put that in there!" She told me a story about how he found the piece on the floor, thought he dropped it, asked my mum if it was Lego, then when she said no, he put it in the bag (I don't know why he didn't just put it in the bin, but okay). I was SURE the bag of spare parts was sealed, so this confused me even more. So I fished the bag out of the bin: you can see the big rip I made in it, but if you look closely, there's a teeny tiny rip at the top too... So I guess my dad just didn't want to spill the spare parts, so he made the tiniest opening he could to put the blue piece in there. The rip was very small and in the seam part of the bag, so I didn't see it and thought it was a sealed bag when I saw the piece in there! (So, SanderDeDycker's comment about the piece possibly getting into the bag after it was opened was 100% correct after all).

I'm marking MMM's answer as the accepted one because they found out what the piece actually is, which is very interesting :)

Sorry for the wild non-Lego related goose chase everyone, the story is kinda funny though (so I'll be keeping the piece)

Comment: This is a funny way for this story to end.  Dads can be wily.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an unofficial LEGO brick, because there is no LEGO print on it and it is not listed in the instruction.

Comment: Does the fact that it came in a sealed bag of LEGO pieces grant it the status of an official LEGO piece though? Like with the rubber band holders and accessory sprues? _ponder_

Comment: Well, if someone drops their button, or false tooth, or wedding ring in the bag accidentally in the factory, that doesn't make **them** official Lego pieces. This would seem to be rather analogous.